# MaterializeCss | With multiselect, cannot pre select all options

Tags: jquery, html, css, multi-select, materialize

I'm trying to implement a multi-select item using [materialized css](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select) for a website. It's all "option" tags should be pre-selected. So I wrote this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var select = $('#visa-type-selection');
    $(select).find("option").prop('selected', true);
    $('#visa-type-selection').material_select();
    alert($( "#visa-type-selection" ).val());
});
```

This code is actually selecting all "options." The alert code below gives this image.
[image]

But material select item looks like this: [image]

And when I click on item, I see none of the "option"s' checkbox is checked:[image]

Materialize creating an "ul", and for each option, creating a checkbox + label in it, and cannot check them if you don't send an onClick action, I suppose. Here is the HTML materialize added:

```
<ul id="select-options-edd3cffe-6107-b8e0-322b-51f667907794" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown multiple-select-dropdown active"
    style="width: 458px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: block;">
    <li class=""><span><input type="checkbox"><label></label>Shengen</span></li>
    <li class=""><span><input type="checkbox"><label></label>İş</span></li>
    <li class=""><span><input type="checkbox"><label></label>Öğrenci</span></li>
    <li class=""><span><input type="checkbox"><label></label>Turist</span></li>
    <li class=""><span><input type="checkbox"><label></label>Emekli</span></li>
    <li class=""><span><input type="checkbox"><label></label>Erasmus</span></li>
</ul>
```

I couldn'd find a workaround because the generated ID of the "ul" tag is changing every time it's created.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with what you say. What you can do is apply jquery .prev() method and access all ul tags. What I did was :- And it helped me in gettig pre selected. you have to access li in the very same and add class Active to them.

```
var a=$('#id_of_multiselect').prev().find(":checkbox");
                    for(var i=0;i<=length_of_list;i++)
                    {
                        a[i].checked=true;
                    }
            $('#egg_events').val(vals).trigger('update');
```

Comment: I canceled the project because of the customer's financial s**ts. So I am not going to give your tip a try for now. But thanks anyway. Maybe one day I will  use this :)

Comment: That's fine! I had the same issue and was going through stack overflow but nothing worked and finally i made something for myself.